# Read CSV file with space as thousand-seperator using pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, file, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a (French) dataset that looks like the following:

```
time;col1;col2;col3
06.09.2017 05:30;329,02;5,7;259
06.09.2017 05:40;500,5;6,6;261
06.09.2017 05:50;521,73;6,7;266
06.09.2017 06:00;1 091,33;9,1;273
06.09.2017 06:10;1 262,43;10;285
```

I try to read it using the following command:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("Example_dataset.csv",
            index_col=0,
            encoding='latin',
            parse_dates=True,
            dayfirst=True,
            sep=';',
            decimal=',',
            thousands=' ')
```

col2 and col3 are recognized as float and integer, though col1 is not recognized as a number because of the thousands-seperator in there. Is there an easy way to read this dataset? Setting `thousands=' '` does not seem to work:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 5 entries, 2017-09-06 05:30:00 to 2017-09-06 06:10:00
Data columns (total 3 columns):
col1    5 non-null object
col2    5 non-null float64
col3    5 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 160.0+ bytes
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try: `df.col1 = df.col1.str.replace(' ', '').astype(float)`

Comment: I just tested on pandas `0.20.1` and your code works, what version are you using?

Comment: That did not work. I think this space is a 'non-breaking space'

I modified your code as follows:
`df.col1 = df.col1.str.replace('\s+', '').str.replace(',','.').astype(float)`

Comment: @zipa, I am using 0.20.2

Comment: @zipa downgrading to 0.20.1 does not solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have non-breaking spaces, I would suggest a more aggressive regular expression with `str.replace`:

```
df.col1 = df.col1.str.replace('[^\d.,e+-]', '')\
               .str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
```

**Regex**

```
[       # character group
^       # negation - ignore everything in this character group
\d      # digit
.       # dot
e       # 'e' - exponent
+-      # signs 
]
```